# suggest me best way to deal dropdown list in django

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models

i'm new to django and i have strucked in development process at chained dropdown list. i tried in several ways but didnot worked for me.The initial dropdown field could be asset type and after selecting the choice next field ie. category should be populate based on asset type and same vice versa for subcategory and model name also.can any one help me to fix this issue.below i'm sharing my code for your reference.

---

models.py code is

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.
class asset_type(models.Model):

    asset_type = models.CharField(max_length=252,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.asset_type

class category(models.Model):
    asset_type = models.ForeignKey('asset_type', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=252,unique=True)     

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class subcategory(models.Model):
    asset_type = models.ForeignKey('asset_type', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey('category',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subcategory = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subcategory
class model_details(models.Model):
    asset_type = models.ForeignKey('asset_type', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey('category',on_delete=models.CASCADE)     
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey("subcategory", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model_name


class stock_in(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    #asset_id = models.ForeignKey(asset_master, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    asset_type = models.CharField(max_length=252)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=252,null=True)
    subcategory = models.CharField(max_length=252)
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    serial_no = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    invoice_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now())
    warranty_date= models.DateField(default=timezone.now())
    vendor_name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    status=models.CharField(max_length=254,default='CURRENT')
    #author = models.CharField(max_length=254,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subcategory
```

forms.py code is

```
class stock_inward(forms.ModelForm):
   asset_type = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.asset_type.objects.none(),empty_label="----SELECT----", widget=forms.Select())
   category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.category.objects.none(),empty_label="----SELECT----", widget=forms.Select())
   subcategory = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.subcategory.objects.none(),empty_label="----SELECT----", widget=forms.Select())
   model_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.model_details.objects.none(),empty_label="----SELECT----", widget=forms.Select())
   #category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.category.objects.none(), required=False,empty_label="----SELECT----", widget=forms.Select())
   #print(category)
   #subcategory = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.subcategory.objects.none(), required=False,empty_label="----SELECT----", widget=forms.Select())
   #model_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.model_details.objects.none(), required=False,empty_label="----SELECT----", widget=forms.Select())
   price = forms.FloatField()
   #subcategory = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.asset_master.objects.order_by().filter(category='SYSTEM').values_list('subcategory', flat=True).distinct(),empty_label='----SELECT----')
   class Meta:
      model = stock_in
      fields = ('asset_type','category','subcategory','model_name','manufacturer','serial_no','invoice_date','warranty_date','vendor_name','price')      
      widgets = {
         #'asset_type':forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.asset_type.objects.all()),
         #'category': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form_control','id':'id_category'}),
         #'subcategory': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form_control','id':'id_subcategory'}),
         'manufacturer': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form_control','id':'id_manufacturer','placeholder':'Made by..'}),
         #'model_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form_control','id':'id_model_name','placeholder':'Ex:SANIAN7'}),
         'serial_no': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form_control','id':'id_serial_no','placeholder':'Enter Serial No..'}),
         'warranty_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'form_control date','id':'id_warranty_date'}),
         'vendor_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form_control','id':'vendor_name','placeholder':'Brought From..'}),
         'price': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form_control','id':'price','placeholder':'Each Price(Incl. GST)'})
   }
   def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
           super(stock_inward,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
           self.fields['asset_type'].choices = list(models.asset_type.objects.values_list('asset_type'))
```

**views.py code is**

````
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from stock.forms import stock_inward
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect,JsonResponse
from django.views.generic import ListView,CreateView,UpdateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from stock import models

# Create your views here.
class StockIn_Form_View(CreateView):
     def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
       context = {'form': stock_inward()}
       return render(request, 'stock/stock_in.html', context)
     def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = stock_inward()
        if request.method=='POST':
          print('POST ACCEPTED')
          form = stock_inward(request.POST)

          if form.is_valid():

               category = form.cleaned_data.get('asset_type')
               subcategory = form.cleaned_data.get('category')
               model_name = form.cleaned_data.get('model_name')

    #          print('value is '+str(category))
    #          print('validated')
               form.save()
    #          f.save()
               result = 'Success'
    #          #context = result
    #          #success_url = reverse_lazy('/stock_in/')
               return redirect('/stock_in/',result=result)
          else:
              result = 'Invalid Input'
              return HttpResponseRedirect('/stock_in/',{'result':result})

          return render(request,'stock/stock_in.html',{'form':form})

def stock_out(request):
    return render(request,'stock/stock_out.html')
def transfer(request):
    return render(request,'stock/transfer.html')

def index(request):
    return render(request,'stock/index.html')

def load_categories(request):
    asset_id = request.GET.get('asset_type')
    categories = models.categories.objects.filter(asset_type=asset_id).order_by('asset_type')
    return render(request, 'dropdown_list/category_options.html', {'categories': categories})

'''

**models.py code is **

    ```
    from django.db import models
    from django.utils import timezone

    # Create your models here.
    class asset_type(models.Model):

        asset_type = models.CharField(max_length=252,unique=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.asset_type

    class category(models.Model):
        asset_type = models.ForeignKey('asset_type', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        category = models.CharField(max_length=252,unique=True)     

        def __str__(self):
            return self.category

    class subcategory(models.Model):
        asset_type = models.ForeignKey('asset_type', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        category = models.ForeignKey('category',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        subcategory = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.subcategory
    class model_details(models.Model):
        asset_type = models.ForeignKey('asset_type', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        category = models.ForeignKey('category',on_delete=models.CASCADE)     
        subcategory = models.ForeignKey("subcategory", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        model_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.model_name


    class stock_in(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        #asset_id = models.ForeignKey(asset_master, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        asset_type = models.CharField(max_length=252)
        category = models.CharField(max_length=252,null=True)
        subcategory = models.CharField(max_length=252)
        manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=254)
        model_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        serial_no = models.CharField(max_length=254)
        invoice_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now())
        warranty_date= models.DateField(default=timezone.now())
        vendor_name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
        price = models.IntegerField()
        created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
        status=models.CharField(max_length=254,default='CURRENT')
        #author = models.CharField(max_length=254,blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.subcategory 

'''

**Let me know if you need more information**
````

Comment: Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601327/populate-dropdown-list-by-another-dropdown-list-in-django-with-formsets

Answer (score 0):

It worked with Ajax call as given below

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script> 
 //category selection
$("#id_asset_type").change(function () {
  console.log('initiated')
  var url = $("#stockinForm").attr("data-categories-url");  // get the url of the `load_cities` view
  var asset_typeId = $(this).val();  // get the selected country ID from the HTML input
  console.log('asset_id'+asset_typeId)
  $.ajax({                       // initialize an AJAX request
    url: url,                    // set the url of the request (= localhost:8000/hr/ajax/load-cities/)
    data: {
      'asset_type': asset_typeId       // add the country id to the GET parameters
    },

    success: function (data) {   // `data` is the return of the `load_cities` view function
      $("#id_category").html(data);  // replace the contents of the city input with the data that came from the server
    }
  });

});
```

with addition to above we have to define URL,render method and a page to display the list.